# Java Hashmap merge function

Tags: java, merge, hashmap, fastutil

I want to build a `HashMap<Integer,Linkedlist<long[]>>` from another nested hashmap.
I have some doubts about **hashmap's merge function**: the function seems to accept just bi-functions which arguments are of the same type.

This implies that when I use the following approach to build this hashmap... (using a function that takes two argument of different type)

```
private static long[] map2longarray(Int2IntMap map){
    //convert hashmap into a long array
}

private static void writeQueryTrace(Long2ObjectOpenHashMap<Int2ObjectOpenHashMap<Int2IntLinkedOpenHashMap>> fqt){
    Int2ObjectOpenHashMap<LinkedList<long[]>> toPrint = new Int2ObjectOpenHashMap<>();
    Int2ObjectOpenHashMap<Int2IntLinkedOpenHashMap> pairQID;
    Int2IntLinkedOpenHashMap QIdDocId;

    for(long pair: fqt.keySet()){
        pairQID = fqt.get(pair);
        for(int qID: pairQID.keySet()) {
            toPrint.merge(qID, map2longarray(pairQID.get(qID)), UnigramQualityModel::mergeList); //<-------ERROR HERE!!!!

        }

    }
}

private static LinkedList<long[]> mergeList(long [] a, LinkedList<long[]> longs) {
    longs.addLast(a);
    return longs;
}
```

...I get the following error:

```
Invalid method reference: LinkedList<long[]> cannot be converted to long[]
```

At this point I modified the map2array function wrapping the long[] array into a LinkedList:

```
private static LinkedList<long[]> map2longarray(Int2IntMap map){
    //convert the map into a long array but WRAPPING IT IN A LINKED LIST
}



  private static void writeQueryTrace(Long2ObjectOpenHashMap<Int2ObjectOpenHashMap<Int2IntLinkedOpenHashMap>> fqt){
//same function as before
   }



private static LinkedList<long[]> mergeList(LinkedList<long[]> a, LinkedList<long[]> longs) {
    longs.addLast(a.getFirst());
    return longs;
}
```

While this version works, at each operation it creates a linked list which is both unnecessary and inefficient: is there a way to avoid the creation of the linked list and stick with the original approach?

Comment: Is that your [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I have modified my question trying to make it more succinct. Is it better?

Comment: The classes I don’t recognize, like `Long2ObjectOpenHashMap`, are they from fastutil? I would love the opportunity to try compiling, modifying and running your code. There’s a (narrow) limit to the effort I’ll make to do so, though.

Comment: yep they are from fastutil

Comment: But yes, it’s better.

Comment: I'm really confused by your data model.  Do you really need a map of linked lists of arrays of long integers?  Without knowing your problem domain, this seems like too many layers.